# Adobe CEP 8 Photoshop-Image-Import

Tags: adobe, adobe-extension

I created a PremierePro Extension which could download and import a file to a project. The same extension unfortunately does not work under Photoshop, because the host scripts app instance doesn't contain a project. I tried out different formats like .psd, but no project appears.

hostScript.jsx:

```
app.project // === null
```

I import the file I downloaded by this command:

```
csInterface.evalScript("app.project.importFiles(['" + fullPath + "'])");
```

Due to the fact that I can't debug the host scripts I'm a bit stucked.
I havn't found an example of importing files to photoshop either.

Does anyone have a clue how to import a file to photoshop, or is there another way to create a explicit project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the open command:

```
csInterface.evalScript("app.open(File('" + encodeURIComponent(fullPath) + "'));");
```

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop doesn't have projects, in fact dom for all of the Adobe products is slightly different. You can check PS JS reference (https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf) for more info. For example you can open files with app.open().
To debug hostscripts I encapsulate everything to functions with try-catch (and never call for dom functions from csinterface), but I think there're also more comprehensive solutions.